# c# 8 NonNullable Reference Types in foreach produce odd warning message

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

When writing the follow code

```
 foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)searchAndReplaceData.RadGridView.ItemsSource ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>())
 {
      object test = item;
      ...
```

I get a warning for the line `object test=item;`:

> CS 8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

How would you handle this scenario? Would I have to write a

```
if (item==null) continue;
```

every time in nullable-save code to ensure that item is not null? Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: If `item` is nullable, you either have to write that if-statement, or use `object? test = item;`, but then you're likely to just move the if-check down below that line. Basically, you need to decide how to deal with null-references now, instead of hoping for the best.

Comment: thanks Lasse! I was hoping for some syntactic sugar for that very common case. if that doesn't exist, I'll just do my version and see what's coming in 9.0 :)

Comment: @Jan it's not C#'s problem. Nothing prevents a list of 10 items from containing 10 nulls. `item` can easily be null. By casting to `IEnumerable` the code erases any type, much less nullability information the compiler could use

Comment: The real solution would be to *not* access the data through `ItemsSource`. Assuming you use data binging, `ItemsSource` binds to some data in your ViewModel or code-behind. Instead of taking a hard dependency on a UI element, it's a lot easier and safer to work with the original data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your hints. I am implementing a search on that grid which comes as a behavior, the hard dependency exists for handling the case of focussing the item if i wound one in the grid anyway. My datasource is also generic to a certain extend as the grid is used for different datatypes. Following your suggestion I would create a dependency property on the search-behavior which I could define as list of something non-nullable. is that how you would do it?

Comment: Are you sure you get a warning exactly how it's written here? I am unable to get the warning using similar code. I am only able to get the warning if I specifically use `IEnumerable<object?>`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/O8s4E7

Comment: @DaveCousineau I think this is a fiddle-bug. see my example: here the itemsource comes from a place where Nullable is not checked and that should be marked as potential error by the compiler (which VS 2019 16.4 does) https://dotnetfiddle.net/7yBlu4

Comment: @DaveCousineau I get the same warning with LinqPad 6. If I use `IEnumerable<Object>` the warning goes away - and I get an NRE if any of the items is `null`. There's no way to know what's hidden behind `ItemSource`, so a null check is always necessary

Comment: @Jan the MVVM way to highlight an item is to bind the `SelectedItem` property of the control to a ViewModel property that actually contains the selected item. Changing that property and raising the `PropertyChanged` event will cause the control to change its own selection.

Comment: @Jan even *without* a ViewModel, you can bind to code-behind properties.

Comment: @Jan you put your code above the `#nullable enable` line. otherwise the `null` in the array gives a warning (you can't put `null` into `object[]` it would have to be `object?[]`. I get the same results in Visual Studio 2019. The code you posted is enumerating over `IEnumerable`. I don't see that you can get the warning that way, since there is no nullability. I at least do not get `object?`s out of `IEnumerable`, I only get `object`s. It's definitely true that they really could be `null`, but they aren't typed that way.

Comment: @DaveCousineau I put it above the enable, because that is what I had with the ItemSource in the questions example. that Itemsource comes from a part of the code I cannot control.if need be, I can post a screenshot from my solution, the issue is very real. But I think we got carried away a bit. so unless you insist, I would stop this discussion here :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos totally agree. your coments gave me some ideas. I see some tests and another round of refactoring coming. thanks for your help/ the discussion!

Comment: @Jan well I'm not trying to get "carried away", I'm trying to answer a question that you've posted. it seems to me unanswerable as written, which means it should be closed unless there is further clarification. something else must be going on with your code in order to get the warning in this situation.

Comment: Your fiddle example still does not give the warning in either the fiddle or VS2019. (ok I am on 16.3.9 not 16.4, I'll try updating I guess)

Comment: @DaveCousineau did not want to be rude, sorry if I came across this way. my original question was answered by Lasse - there is no nicer way to solve that issue. the other discussion was a bit more general and helped me a lot,
As for 16.3 vs. 16.4 I can imagine this being the reason. looking forward for your feedback!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203722/discussion-between-dave-cousineau-and-jan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the case when enumerating an `IEnumerable` as in the code you posted that in .NET Core 3.0 and in .NET Framework the enumeration yields `object`, whereas in .NET Core 3.1 the enumeration yields `object?`, which is why you get the warning.

It does make some sense to yield `object?` from `IEnumerable` since there is no indication of the nullability of the contents.

If you think there may truly be `null`s in the collection, then you need to decide what to do with them. If you just want to ignore them, you can filter them out. This is basically equivalent to your `if (item == null) continue;` line.

```
var maybeSource = (IEnumerable<object?>?)searchAndReplaceData.RadGridView.ItemsSource;
var maybeNullItems = maybeSource ?? Enumerable.Empty<object?>();

var items = maybeNullItems.Where(maybeNullItem => maybeNullItem != null);

// items is automatically inferred to be IEnumerable<object>

foreach (var item in items) {
   ...
```

or if you think it should not be possible for any of the items to actually be `null`, you should throw instead (so that you will know right away if/when you are wrong).

```
var maybeSource = (IEnumerable<object?>?)searchAndReplaceData.RadGridView.ItemsSource;
var maybeNullItems = maybeSource ?? Enumerable.Empty<object?>();

var someAreNull = maybeNullItems.Any(maybeNullItem => maybeNullItem == null);
if (someAreNull)
   throw new ShouldNotBeNullException(); // made-up exception for this purpose

var items = (IEnumerable<object>)maybeNullItems;

foreach (var item in items) {
   ...
```

Note that it is possible to write various helper methods to clean up this kind of code quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments by friendly folks, I could define the problem more narrowly.

**The short answer is: yes you have to make that `if (item==null) continue;` check to avoid that warning and be on the save side.**

Since the compiler does not always show warnings as - at least I would have expected,  here's some sample code that may help others to understand the current limitations of null-reference-checking. especially when working with 3rd party code that does not check for null-references yet.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

#nullable disable
public static class NullableDisabled3rdPartyClass
{
    public static object UnclearNullableStateEnumerableAsObject()
    {
        IEnumerable<object> objects = new object[] { 1, 2, 3, null };
        return objects;
    }
}

#nullable enable

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var thing in (IEnumerable)NullableDisabled3rdPartyClass.UnclearNullableStateEnumerableAsObject() ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>())
        {
            object item = thing; //Shows the warning CS8600
            //Console.WriteLine(item.ToString()); //crashes
        }

        //does not show any warning but also crashes on thing.toString
        foreach (var thing in (IEnumerable<object>)NullableDisabled3rdPartyClass.UnclearNullableStateEnumerableAsObject() ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>())
        {
            object item = thing; //no warning
            //Console.WriteLine(thing.ToString()); //crashes
        }

        //does not help either
        var x = NullableDisabled3rdPartyClass.UnclearNullableStateEnumerableAsObject() as IEnumerable<object>;
        foreach (var thing in x ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>())
        {
            object item = thing; //no warning
            //Console.WriteLine(item.ToString()); //crashes
        }

        //shows no warning and does not crash
        foreach (var thing in (IEnumerable)NullableDisabled3rdPartyClass.UnclearNullableStateEnumerableAsObject() ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>())
        {
            if (thing == null) continue;
            object item = thing;
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```