# Null warnings when looping through Regex.MatchCollection (C#)

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have this `foreach` loop that is used to process Regex matches.

```cs
var silences = new List<Silence>();

foreach (Match match in RegexPatterns.Silence.Matches(results.ToString()))                   //[1]
   silences.Add(new Silence()
   {
      Start = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(match.Groups[RegexGroups.Start].Value)),     //[2]
      ExclusiveEnd = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(match.Groups[RegexGroups.End].Value)) //[3]
   });
```

`RegexPatterns` is a static class with get only auto-properties that return Regex object. It has been tested and works just fine.

`RegexGroups` is a struct with constant string fields.
`results` is a `StringBuilder()` and as far as I know is is initialized to `String.Empty`

> Warning   CS8600  Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

This one is given for `match` in line [1]. I changed `Match` to `Match?` and did away with that warning.

> CS8602    Dereference of a possibly null reference.

This one is given for `match` in line [2]. I changed `match` to `match!` and did away with that warning. Im farly confident that I can do this because AFAIK `Regex.Matches()` will at least return an empty `MatchCollection`, never null.

My question is why did I get a *CS8602* warning in line [2] but not line [3].

I know this is a trivial question, but I just don't understand how line [3] passed muster, but line [2] got flagged for possible null dereference.

Comment: If you added more complete code, it would be a lot easier to answer. I paste this into my IDE, and I get a *sea of red*

Comment: For the error at line [1], see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188924/c-sharp-8-nonnullable-reference-types-in-foreach-produce-odd-warning-message

Comment: This warning should go away once you update to .NET 5: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/37918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error at line 1 is covered in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59188924/5311735). `MatchCollection` has `GetEnumerator` which returns non-generic `IEnumerable`, and when you enumerate it - C# treats each item as `object?`, because it indeed has no idea whether the result can be null or not, so safe assumption is to treat it as nullable. You then implicitly convert that `object?` to (non-nullable) `Match`, hence the warning.

When you change `Match` to `Match?` in foreach, now compiler treats `match` as nullable, so issues another warning when you access `match.Groups` without check. If control flow managed to pass to line [3] - that means `match` was actually not null, so there is no need to issue this warning for every access. And so there is no need to do `match!.Groups` on every access either, only on first one, to let compiler know you are sure this variable is not null.

You can also use `for` loop like this to avoid nullable warnings (just an option):

```
var matches = RegexPatterns.Silence.Matches(results.ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++) {
    var match = matches[i];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looing for.